# Hadoop on OSX "Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore"

Tags: macos, hadoop, osx-lion

I am getting this error on startup of Hadoop on OSX 10.7:

> Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
>   put: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create directory /user/travis/input/conf. Name node is in safe mode.

It doesn't appear to be causing any issues with the functionality of Hadoop.

Comment: It looks like this is an open issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7489

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Matthew Buckett's suggestion in HADOOP-7489 worked for me.  Add the following to your hadoop-env.sh file:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm=OX.AC.UK -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc0.ox.ac.uk:kdc1.ox.ac.uk"
```

Comment: I don't have a hadoop-env.sh because I'm just compiling against hadoop but I'm running into this issue. Could I set this flags on my gradle script or something?

Answer (score 39):

As an update to this (and to address [David Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1698695/david-williams)' point about Java 1.7), I experienced that only setting the `.realm` and `.kdc` properties was insufficient to stop the offending message.

However, by examining the [source file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/macosx-port/macosx-port/jdk/file/0785fa5940f6/src/share/classes/sun/security/krb5/Config.java) that is omitting the message I was able to determine that setting the `.krb5.conf` property to `/dev/null` was enough to suppress the message. Obviously if you actually have a krb5 configuration, better to specify the actual path to it.

In total, my `hadoop-env.sh` snippet is as follows:

```
HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/dev/null"
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was the only answer that worked on Java 1.7 on OS X!

Comment: Works brilliantly for me

Comment: It worked also for me (but only at the second restart, this is quite puzzling) on OS X 10.10.1 and Java 1.7. Thanks.

Comment: This issue can appear in hbase (OS X Yosemite). Extending HBAE_OPTS in hbase-env.sh as follows can resolve it.

`export HBASE_OPTS="${HBASE_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
export HBASE_OPTS="${HBASE_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/dev/null"`

Answer (score 16):

I'm having the same issue on OS X 10.8.2, Java version 1.7.0_21. Unfortunately, the above solution does not fix the problem with this version :(

**Edit:** I found the solution to this, based on a hint I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716910/still-getting-unable-to-load-realm-info-from-scdynamicstore-after-bug-fix). In the `hadoop-env.sh` file, change the `JAVA_HOME` setting to:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
```

(Note the grave quotes here.)

Comment: I had the same problem, and this was the fix for me.

Comment: I was facing this problem for HBase, adding this line to conf/hbase-env.sh fixed the issue for me.

Comment: A simpler example of this same problem can also be found in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716910/still-getting-unable-to-load-realm-info-from-scdynamicstore-after-bug-fix

Answer (score 13):

FYI, you can simplify this further by only specifying the following:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
```

This is mentioned in HADOOP-7489 as well.

Comment: The answer used to work for me but is no longer working on java 1.7 and hadoop 1.2.1.  Is there an updated solution?

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem on MacOS and after trying different combinations this is what worked for me universally (both Hadoop 1.2 and 2.2):

in `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh` set the following lines:

```
# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="

# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This worked for me; probably worth mentioning that I was working with Hbase so had to change HADOOP_OPTS to HBASE_OPTS throughout.

Answer (score 4):

and also add

`YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -Djava.security.krb5.realm=OX.AC.UK -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc0.ox.ac.uk:kdc1.ox.ac.uk"`

before executing start-yarn.sh (or start-all.sh) on cdh4.1.3

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when debugging MapReduce from Eclipse, but it was a red herring. The real problem was that I should have been remote debugging by adding debugging parameters to the JAVA_OPTS

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044
```

And then creating a new "Remote Java Application" profile in the debug configuration that pointed to port 1044.

[This article](http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/04/13/how-to-debug-solr-with-eclipse/) has some more in-depth information about the debugging side of things. It's talking about Solr, but works much the same with Hadoop. If you have trouble, stick a message below and I'll try to help.