# Still getting "Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore" after bug fix

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, homebrew

I installed `Hadoop` and `Pig` using `brew install hadoop` and `brew install pig`.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134723/hadoop-on-osx-unable-to-load-realm-info-from-scdynamicstore) that you will to get `Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore` error message unless you add:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm=OX.AC.UK -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc0.ox.ac.uk:kdc1.ox.ac.uk"
```

to your `hadoop-env.sh` file, which I have.

However, when I run `hadoop namenode -format`, I still see:

```
java[1548:1703] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
```

amongst the outputs.

Anyone know why I'm still getting it?

Answer (score 10):

As dturnanski suggests, you need to use an older JDK. You can set this in the `hadoop-env.sh` file by changing the `JAVA_HOME` setting to:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
```

(Note the grave quotes here.) This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with java 7. works with java 6

Comment: @kewpiedoll99 did you find out solution for intellij?

Comment: @Tad - I think ultimately I just had to run from the command line. Either that or it was a mismatch of versions. Sorry, it's been too long and I don't remember.