# Installing, Configuring, and running Hadoop 2.2.0 on Mac OS X

Tags: java, bash, hadoop

I've installed hadoop 2.2.0, and set up everything (for a single node) based on this tutorial here: [Hadoop YARN Installation](http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide/#mrconfig). However, I can't get hadoop to run.

I think my problem is that I can't connect to my localhost, but I'm not really sure why.  I've spent upwards of about 10 hours installing, googling, and hating open-source software installation guides, so I've now turned to the one place that has never failed me.

Since a picture is worth a thousand words, I give you my set up ... in many many <strike>words</strike> pictures:

---

## Basic profile/setup

I'm running Mac OS X (Mavericks 10.9.5)

[image: sharing]

For whatever it's worth, here's my `/etc/hosts` file:

[image: hosts]

My bash profile:

[image: bash]

---

## Hadoop file configurations

The setup for `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml`:

[image: core-hdfs.xlm]

***note***: I have created folders in the locations you see above

The setup for my `yarn-site.xml`:

[image: yarn]

Setup for my `hadoop-env.sh` file:

[image: hadoop-env]

---

## Side Note

Before I show the results of when I run `start-dfs.sh`, `start-yarn.sh`, and check to see what's running with `jps`, keep in mind that I have a `hadoop` pointing to `hadoop-2.2.0`.

[image: pointer]

---

## Starting up Hadoop

Now, here's the results of when I start the deamons up:

[image: startitup]

For those of you who don't have a microscope (it looks super small on the preview of this post), here's a code chunk of what shows above:

> mrp:~ mrp$ start-dfs.sh
>   2014-11-08 13:06:05.695 java[17730:1003] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
>   14/11/08 13:06:05 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   Starting namenodes on [localhost]
>   localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/hadoop-mrp-namenode-mrp.local.out
>   localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/hadoop-mrp-datanode-mrp.local.out
>   localhost: 2014-11-08 13:06:10.954 java[17867:1403] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
>   Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
>   0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/hadoop-mrp-secondarynamenode-mrp.local.out
>   0.0.0.0: 2014-11-08 13:06:16.065 java[17953:1403] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
>   2014-11-08 13:06:20.982 java[17993:1003] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
>   14/11/08 13:06:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>
> mrp:~ mrp$ start-yarn.sh
>   starting yarn daemons
>   starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-mrp-resourcemanager-mrp.local.out
>   2014-11-08 13:06:43.765 java[18053:20b] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
>   localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/yarn-mrp-nodemanager-mrp.local.out

Check to see what's running:

[image: jps]

---

## Time Out

OK.  So far, I think, so good.  At least this looks good based on all the other tutorials and posts. I think.

Before I try to do anything fancy, I'll just want to see if it's working properly, and run a simple command like `hadoop fs -ls`.

---

## Failure

When I run `hadoop fs -ls`, here's what I get:

[image: fail]

Again, in case you can't see that pic, it says:

> 2014-11-08 13:23:45.772 java[18326:1003] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
>   14/11/08 13:23:45 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   ls: Call From mrp.local/127.0.0.1 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I've tried to run other commands, and I get the same basic error in the beginning of everything:

> Call From mrp.local/127.0.0.1 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Now, I've gone to that website mentioned, but honestly, everything in that link means nothing to me.  I don't get what I should do.

I would very much appreciate any assistance with this. You'll make me the ***happiest hadooper***, ever.

...this should go without saying, but obviously I'd be happy to edit/update with more info if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've got Hadoop up and running. I had two problems (I think).

1. When starting up the NameNode and DataNode, I received the following error: `Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore.`

To fix this, I added the following two lines to my `hadoop-env.sh` file:

> HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
>   HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/dev/null"

I found those two lines in the solution to this post, [Hadoop on OSX "Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134723/hadoop-on-osx-unable-to-load-realm-info-from-scdynamicstore).  The Answer was posted by Matthew L Daniel.

2. I had formatted the NameNode folder more than once, which apparently screws things up?

I can't verify this screws things up, because I don't have any errors in any of my log files, however once I followed **Workaround 1** (deleting & recreating NameNode/DataNode folders, then reformatting) on this post, [No data nodes are started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097246/no-data-nodes-are-started), I was able to load up the DataNode and get everything working.

Answer (score 1):

add these to `.bashrc`

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

Comment: does it have to be `.bashrc` or can it be `.bash_profile`?

Comment: it is better to put all your configs in .bashrc

Comment: OK. I'm now using .bashrc instead of .bash_profile. I've included the `exports` mentioned, however now the DataNode won't start (doesn't show up when I type in `jps`).

Comment: I just realized that I didn't include the `hadoop-evn.sh`. I will update my question with that info now..

Comment: Not sure what this did, but now I definitely can't start the DataNode anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Had a very similar problem and found this question while googling for a solution.

Here is how I could resolve it (on Mac OS 10.10 with Hadoop 2.5.1). Not sure if the question is exactly the same problem: I checked the log files generated by the data-node (/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/hadoop-mrp-datanode-mrp.local.out) and found the following entry:

```
2014-11-09 17:44:35,238 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:
Exception in namenode join org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: 
Directory /private/tmp/hadoop-kthul/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage
directory does not exist or is not accessible.
```

Based on this, I concluded that something is wrong with the HDFS data on the datanode.

I deleted the directory with the HDFS data and reformatted HDFS:

```
rm -rf /private/tmp/hadoop-kthul
hdfs namenode -format
```

Now, I am up and running again. Still wondering if /private/tmp is a good place to keep the HDSF data - looking options to change this.

Comment: I didn't have any errors in my logs, so this didn't exactly solve my problem, but it helped get me there!  I will post the solution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Since native library isn't supported on Mac, if you want to suppress this warning:

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Add this to the log4j.properties in ${HADOOP_HOME}/libexec/etc/hadoop:

```
# Turn of native library warning
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader=ERROR
```